# Twitter bootstrap tabs and javascript events

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap for a project - in particular its tab functions (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)

Now I have this tablist and when I press the tab it switches to the content of each individual tab. However, this content is preloaded in the page (the html code for the content of all tabs is already there, you only change the visibility by pressing the tabs).

However I want to only dynamically load content when a certain tab is pressed, so one will get the latest data instead of the data when the whole page was loaded.

I am planning on using jQuery for this. However, how can I make it that when a tab is pressed a certain jquery function is called?

I tried to show an alert when a tab was clicked (if that works, a jQuery function will too), but even that isn't working:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.tabs').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.target(window.alert("hello"))
    });
});
</script>
```

And my html:

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">tab 2</li>
</ul>

<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
      <h1>Tab1</h1>
      <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
     <h1>Tab2</h1>
     <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Any idea on how to make this work?**

see this for the workings of twitter bootstrap tabs: (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)
and the js file it uses:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-tabs.js

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The bind seems to run before the DOM is ready. In addition, your selector seems to be broken and you can bind change only on select elements. You have to work around by clicking and implementing some logic. Try

```
$(function() {
    $('.tabs').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.target(window.alert("hello"))
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

After consulting with the documentation, it seems that your code was only missing the DOM ready part, the rest wasn't actually a bug, which means that according to the docs the following should work:

```
$(function() {
    $('.tabs').bind('change', function (e) {
        // e.target is the new active tab according to docs
        // so save the reference in case it's needed later on
        window.activeTab = e.target;
        // display the alert
        alert("hello");
        // Load data etc
    });
});
```

What caused confusion is that the plugin overrides default selector, making `#.tabs` valid and also adding a change event to the tab element. Go figure why they decided this syntax was a great idea.

Anyways you can try the second sample and comment wether the alert is fired before or after the tab change.

EDIT: fixed jquery exception caused by `#.tabs` selector

Comment: this one works! However, it now shows the alert before it shows the new tab. How can I make it that first the new tab is shown and then the alert is displayed?

Comment: @Javaaaa it's difficult to say, please update the code in your question to reflect the current "working" state, when alert is fired before.

Comment: done! I am asking because when i click a tab, a jqquery function should get some data and when it has retrieved that populate the tabs' div with that data. As it is now, it first shows the alert and only when i click ok changes the tab. Will it be the same with retrieving data, in that it will wait until the data is retrieved and only then change the tab?

Comment: @Javaaaa I added some additional information to the answer, try that and reply how it works out, according to docs, it should be OK.

Comment: alternatively, Is it possible to make a eventlistener that checks which tab is active? (not only on load, but also after interaction with the tabs)?

Comment: thanks again, but the second solution doesn't show a window at all.

Comment: You could store the active tab in a variable and whenever you need it, just read from the variable. The other solution would be to look for the appropriate CSS properties to see which are shown and which are hidden.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Maybe try just calling alert('hello'); inside the event handler.

Comment: how could I store the active tab in a variable? (something with this.?)

Comment: @Javaaaa The easiest way would be to have a global variable, which is set in the event handler. Like `window.activeTab = e.target` and every time you need the active tab, you can refer to it by `activeTab`.

Comment: This is not working at all. $('#.tabs') is causing an exception in JQuery, I have tried all combinations - the only thing working is binding a click event.

Comment: This approach used to work nicely, but for the current version you should go with @Mike Grace answer

Answer (score 73):

With Twitter Bootstrap version 2 the [documented way to subscribe to tab change events](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs) is

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
  e.target // activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous tab
})
```

The latest documentation on Twitter Bootstrap tab events can be found at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: If you want to load content into the <div> belonging to the tab, you can use `$($(e.target).attr('href'))` (in the event handler) to find that <div>.

Comment: Sometimes, its best scrolling to the bottom of the page. Thanks!

Comment: With Bootstrap 3, you need to use 'shown.bs.tab' instead of 'shown'

Answer (score 19):

If you are using 2.3.2 and it's not working, try using:

```
$(document).on("shown", 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
     console.log('showing tab ' + e.target); // Active Tab
     console.log('showing tab ' + e.relatedTarget); // Previous Tab
});
```

2.3.2 tabs usage: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs

If you are playing with version 3 (currently RC2) then documentation shows

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
     console.log('showing tab ' + e.target); // Active Tab
     console.log('showing tab ' + e.relatedTarget); // Previous Tab
 })
```

RC2 Tabs Usage: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following snippet of code in bootstrap 3

```
$(document).on( 'shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
   var activatedTab = e.target; // activated tab
})
```

Comment: Works great except that it doesn't fire on the first tab which is already loaded on the document load?

Answer (score 0):

How about using click? Like this:

```
$('#.tabs').click(function (e) {
  e.target(window.alert("hello"))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your syntax relating to the selector:

```
$('#.tabs') // should be ...
$('.tabs');
```

The unordered list has the **class** called 'tabs' in your HTML, whereas you were originally trying to select an element with the **id** '.tabs'.

And you'll have to take manticore's suggestion into account too. You can only use 'change' on form elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('tab clicked!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) says: use event `show`.