# Required validation on hidden field

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, hidden-field

I am using client side validation on hidden field in asp.net MVC. I am using required validation using data annotations. I am trying to validate hidden field but it’s not working.

My Model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "From date is required")]
 public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
```

My View

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FromDate, new { ID = "hfdFromDate" }

 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromDate)
```

I would like to know how I can achieve the same, any small inputs on the same is also greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP MVC jquery validation in bootsrap tabs causes an undesired postback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844336/asp-mvc-jquery-validation-in-bootsrap-tabs-causes-an-undesired-postback)

Comment: Can you check if the receiving object on your method contains the data on the hidden field? If so, can you also check if ModelState.IsValid()?

Comment: How would you set value in hidden field. If user is not setting value in hidden field then there is no need of hidden field. And if you are setting value in hidden field there will not be need of required field validation.

Answer (score 2):

As some have pointed the validation isn't performed because the "hidden" property is set.
I had the same issue and ended up using the style tag:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foo, new {  style = "visibility:hidden"})
```

The validation is then performed.

Answer (score 0):

Added this line before form.valid().

```
form.data("validator").settings.ignore = "";
```

where form is your form element.
In my case :

```
var form = $("#myForm");
```