# How to display validation errors on page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I am creating a feature in my app to process an uploaded CSV file containing multiple records to be imported. Data needs to be validated, and I want to show any validation errors BEFORE the **Import** button is clicked. High-level plan:

- Step 1: Upload CSV file
- Step 2: Display all records from CSV file and any validation errors next to each record (missing required fields, etc.)
- Step 3: Click "Import" in order to actually import the valid records.

Here's a simplified version of what I have:

## User View Model

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

## File Upload Action Post

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase csvFile)
{
    // var csvRecords = do stuff to retrieve data from CSV file
    var newUsersToCreate = new List<UserViewModel>();

    foreach (var csvRecord in csvRecords)
    {
        newUsersToCreate.Add(new UserViewModel
        {
            Name = csvRecord.Name,
            Email = csvRecord.Email,
            Phone = csvRecord.Phone
        });
    }
    return View("ImportPreview", newUsersToCreate);
}
```

## View ImportPreview.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<App.ViewModels.UserViewModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "alert alert-danger", role = "alert" })

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Validation Errors</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model)
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Import</button>
}
```

## Editor Template for UserViewModel.cshtml

```
@model App.ViewModels.UserViewModel

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Phone)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Phone)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

## Problem

While this generates a nice "preview" table with all prepared `User` records as essentially rows of hidden fields ready to go, the problem is that it does not display validation errors until the **Import** button is clicked.

How can I get it to show per-field validation errors in each row, right after the `return View('ImportPreview', newUsersToCreate)` comes back with the view?

Comment: One option would be to add a script to validate the form when the page is loaded - `$('form').valid();`

Comment: You might also be able to use `TryValidateModel(newUsersToCreate); in the controller after you populate it to add the `ModelStateErrors` (not tested)

Comment: I tried both of these already, but no success. Not sure if it's got anything to do with these being hidden fields.

Comment: Sorry, did not notice that. By default, hidden inputs are not validated in the view, but your can override that

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844336/asp-mvc-jquery-validation-in-bootsrap-tabs-causes-an-undesired-postback/35856410#35856410) for an example. But since they are hidden, the user cannot edit them, so not sure how showing errors will help

Comment: Fair point, I left out some of that back story. The idea would be that they would need to go and fix their CSV file and re-upload.

Comment: Sounds like it would be better to validate in the controller then (and just be able to display a message to the user that their file is not valid if that's the case)?

Comment: True, validating in the controller would be fine. But I'd like to provide more feedback than just simply stating that CSV file is invalid. Seems reasonable to say "such-and-such field in such-and-such row is missing" and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154050/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-jiveman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in the view by checking if the `$.validator` is valid. Since hidden inputs are not validated by default, you also need to override the validator. Add the following after the `jquery-{version}.js`, `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts (but not in `$(document).ready()`)

```
<script>
    // override validator to include hidden inputs
    $.validator.setDefaults({ 
        ignore: [] 
    });
    // validate form and display errors
    $('form').valid();
</script>
```

Note that you might include a (say) `<p id="error" style="display:none;">` tag containing a 'general' error message that the data is invalid and use

```
if ($('form').valid()) {
    $('#error').show();
}
```

The disadvantage is that you need to include the jQuery scripts that otherwise are not needed.

Another option is to validate in the controller using `TryValidateObject` on each item in the collection, and add any errors to `ModelState` which will be displayed in your `ValidationMessageFor()` placeholders. Note the following assumes `csvRecords` implements `IList<T>` so that you can use a `for` loop.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase csvFile)
{
    // var csvRecords = do stuff to retrieve data from CSV file
    var newUsersToCreate = new List<UserViewModel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < csvRecords.Count; i++)
    {
        UserViewModel model = new UserViewModel
        {
            Name = csvRecords[i].Name,
            ....
        };
        newUsersToCreate.Add(model);
        // validate the model and include the collection indexer
        bool isValid = ValidateModel(model, i));   
    }
    return View("ImportPreview", newUsersToCreate);
}

private bool ValidateModel(object model, int index) 
{ 
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>(); 
    var context = new ValidationContext(model); 
    if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, validationResults, true)) 
    { 
        foreach (var error in validationResults) 
        { 
            string propertyName = $"[{index}].{error.MemberNames.First()}"; 
            ModelState.AddModelError(propertyName, error.ErrorMessage); 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

The advantage of the controller code is that you could add an additional property to your view model (say `bool IsValid`) and use it for conditional styling of your table rows, and that you could decide that if there are 'too many' errors, you could just display a different view rather that rendering the whole table and displaying potentially hundreds of repeated error messages

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I went with the 2nd approach, because it seems better to take care of validation in the controller and deliver the pre-validated model to the view, in my use case. Thanks!