# How to check validation of each object separately?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

This my class `Obj` and `Action`. But `ModelState.isValid` checks the whole array `obj`, but I need a separate object in each cycle to check whether it pass validation.

```
public class Obj
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required.")]
        [Range(1000, 2019, ErrorMessage = "Year of publication must be between 1000 and 2017.")]
        [Display(Name = "Year of publication")]
        public int Year { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Desc { get; set; }

    }


public ActionResult Create(Obj[] obj)
{
    foreach (var b in obj)
    {
        if (ModalState.isValid)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Did you put data annotations into `Obj` class? Show us how it looks like?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what your question is.  Are you wanting to validate each object in the array, one at a time instead of the entire array with the built in validation techniques and if so, why? Understanding your motivation/reason can help us craft an answer.

Comment: As @klabranche has noted, its unclear why you want to do this, but the 2nd option in [How to display validation errors on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137284/how-to-display-validation-errors-on-page-load/46138135#46138135) shows how you can validate each item individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate manually with the data annotations you can create your own ValidationContext for the object in question and then run TryValidateObject for each of the objects.

```
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
foreach (var b in obj)
{

    var context = new ValidationContext(b);
    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(b,context,validationResults);
    'do whatever.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these methods: TryValidateModel or ValidateModel

Comment: These methods checks the whole array obj too.