# ASP.Net Core MVC - Validation Summary not working with bootstrap tabs and dynamically loaded content

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, tabs, loaded

How do you get dynamically loaded tabs to work in ASP.Net Core MVC?

1. I have a simple Index.cshtml that uses bootstrap tabs to create two tabs from the a tags on the page.  (To test out options, I first copied from https://qawithexperts.com/article/asp.net/bootstrap-tabs-with-dynamic-content-loading-in-aspnet-mvc/176)
2. There is a click event on each tab that uses $.ajax() to call the controller and then set the html of the appropriate div.
3. I have a model with one field, a string that is required.
4. I have the create view that Visual Studio created.
5. When I run it and click the first tab, the controller returns PartialView("FirstTabCreate") and loads into the div and everything looks great.
6. The problem is when clicking the "Create" button.
7. **The controller method checks if IsValid on the ModelState.  If not, here is where I run into a problem.  If I return the partial view and the model that was passed in I see my validation errors as expected but because I returned the partial view, I lose my tabs.  If I return the main view (Index) then the javascript reloads my partial view and has lost the ModelState at that point.**

I am not sure what to return so that this works.  I have seen lots of examples online that use dynamically loaded tabs but none of them have models or validation.

Code below:
Index Page

```
@model FirstTab
<!-- Tab Buttons -->
<ul id="tabstrip" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#FirstTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Submission</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#SecondTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Search</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab Content Containers -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="FirstTab">
       
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="SecondTab">

    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#tabstrip a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var tabID = $(this).attr("href").substr(1);
        $(".tab-pane").each(function () {
            console.log("clearing " + $(this).attr("id") + " tab");
            $(this).empty();
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "/@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]/" + tabID,
            cache: false,
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#" + tabID).html(result);
            }

        });
        $(this).tab('show');
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tabstrip a')[0].click();
    });
</script>
```

FirstTabCreate View

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.FirstTab

<h4>FirstTab</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <form asp-action="FirstTabCreate">        
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class FirstTab
    {
        [Required()]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {       
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult FirstTab()
        {
            return PartialView("FirstTabCreate");
        }

        public ActionResult FirstTabCreate(FirstTab model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("FirstTabCreate",  model);
            }
            return Content("Success");
        }

        public ActionResult SecondTab()
        {
            return PartialView("_SecondTab");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like it but to get it to work, when I click Save, in the Controller method I check if the ModelState is valid.  If not, I put the keys and values into a list of custom class and then put that list in the cache.  When the child partial view loads it checks to see if there is anything in the cache and if so, parses it back out and uses ModelState.AddModelError().

It's not pretty but it does allow the validation to work.

Answer (score 0):

try to add jquery validation scripts in your code
delete this

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and use this instead

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but no, that did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your @section Scripts

```
@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
<script>
    $.validator.setDefaults({ 
        ignore: [] 
    });
</script>
```

}

Note: do not add the above inside $(document).ready()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is reference here as useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35856410/838023